# Trying to run Google Chrome and Maps on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, google, google-maps

I can download google chrome and maps on Ubuntu 16.04 but I cannot get them to install or run. I even tried some suggested commands in terminal but they just dead ended. When I press the Install button on the GUI it only engages momentarily and the GUI has a message about non free third party software but Google isn't asking for any kind of payment and they never have on any of my other OS's. I copied and pasted some suggested commands to terminal which did start the installation but then it just dead ended at another prompt and there were no error messages. I downloaded the versions of chrome and maps that google said were for Ubuntu 64 bit.Also this is a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on a freshly DOD wiped 300Gb hard drive.

Comment: Please don't post the same exact question when you can just edit the old question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

There was a bug when 16.04 first came out that made it difficult or impossible to install third-party .deb packages through the graphical software manager. However, Canonical has released an update that fixes the issue.

Install all the available software updates for your system, log out and log back in, and you should be able to install Google Chrome.

Comment: all available updates were supposed to be installed already. I rebooted and now I a STUPID red dot with a minus sign telling me there is an error and to run a package manager from a right click mehbnn

Comment: menu that isnt there. Terminal says broken count <0. Ive succesfully installed Google both my Windows PC and my Mac What the F is wrong with ubuntu maybe I should wipe this defective OS and install RED HAT instead!

Comment: Yes Im pissed you would think that if someone would write an OS that one of the FIRST things they would do is make sure it was compatible with GOOGLE!

Comment: Canonical needs to go back to the drawing  board and start over

Comment: Logged out and back in again and all Im getting is more errors

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what the errors are. Feel free to edit your question to include the text of any error messages if you'd like help with them here. Or you're welcome to install Red Hat Linux if that's going to work better for you.